# Perl regexp tr// "I dont get why it does this?"

Tags: regex, perl

I did the following to my string $text

```
$text =~ tr/a-zåàâäæçéèêëîïôöœßùûüÿA-ZÅÀÂÄÆÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖŒÙÛÜŸ'()\-,.?!:;/\n/cs;
```

What this did was to split the string in newlines. This is what I wanted to do

> but I dont get why it does this?

I thought that this line would take all chars a-zåàâäæçéèêëîïôöœßùûüÿA-ZÅÀÂÄÆÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖŒÙÛÜŸ'()-,.?!:; and replace each of them with \n

I dont get what cs in the end does either. [Here](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-tr.html) you can get an explanation of cs but I dont understand what it means:

> "c - is used to specify that the SEARCHLIST character set is
>   complemented"
>
> "s - is used to specify that the sequences of characters that were
>   transliterated to the same character are squashed down to a single
>   instance of the character"

**Example:**

```
$text= "a ar? å ..";
```

gives

a 
ar?
å
 
..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "c - is used to specify that the SEARCHLIST character set is complemented"

This means that it will replace anything **not** in the search list with `\n`. In your example, the only character not in the search list is a space. Therefore each space gets replaced with a newline. As Schwern [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752044/176646), this is not a good way to do this.

> "s - is used to specify that the sequences of characters that were transliterated to the same character are squashed down to a single instance of the character"

This means that if three characters in a row are translated (resulting in three `\n` in a row), the three `\n` will be "squashed" into a single `\n`. If you added some spaces to your example input, you could see this in action:

```
# Multiple spaces separating words
my $str = "a   ar?  å";
```

Without squashing:

```
$str =~ tr/a-zåàâäæçéèêëîïôöœßùûüÿA-ZÅÀÂÄÆÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖŒÙÛÜŸ'()\-,.?!:;/\n/c;
```

Outputs:

```
a



ar?


å
```

With squashing:

```
$str =~ tr/a-zåàâäæçéèêëîïôöœßùûüÿA-ZÅÀÂÄÆÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖŒÙÛÜŸ'()\-,.?!:;/\n/cs;
```

Outputs:

```
a
ar?
å
```

Answer (score 5):

> **c** - is used to specify that the SEARCHLIST character set is complemented

In this usage, ["complemented"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) is similar to "negated" or "reversed", so instead of replacing the characters listed in your expression every character **not** found in your expression is replaced.  In your example string this means that all of the spaces are replaced with a newline because every other character is included in the set.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to turn all spaces into newlines, listing out all the things which are *not* spaces is cumbersome and you're likely to forget some.  You can instead work directly on the spaces with a regex.

```
s{\s+}{\n}g;
```

`s{...}{...}` is a "search and replace" using regular expressions rather than just characters.  `\s` is regex speak for "whitespace" which includes spaces, tabs and newlines.  `+` says to match 1 or more of them, so multiple spaces in a row will be turned into one newline.  The `g` modifier says to do it "globally" or across every character in the string, otherwise it would stop at the first match.

```
foo bar     baz
```

Becomes

```
foo
bar
baz
```